# How to install java using rpm file in Unix

Tags: java, bash, unix

I have downloaded JDK 7 rpm file into my 64-bit Unix box and trying to install Java using command:

```
rpm -ivh jdk-7u17-linux-x64.rpm
```

but I am getting this error:

```
error: can't create transaction lock on /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock (Permission denied)
```

Please help me how to install Java in my Unix box. I am using bash shell also I don't have root credentials.

Comment: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64rpm_install.xml. try with super user access. sudo rpm -ivh jdk-7u17-linux-x64.rpm

Answer (score 0):

try to use sudo command

`sudo rpm -ivh jdk-7u17-linux-x64.rpm`

Answer (score 0):

If you are in sudoers list, try `sudo rpm -ivh jdk-7u17-linux-x64.rpm`.
If you don't, then system admin is your saviour.

Comment: I am getting error when I use `sudo` command : `ora is not allowed to run sudo on <hostname>.  This incident will be reported.`

Comment: The username that you are using is not in the sudoers list. Ask your system admin or a user with root privilege to install it for you.